# Compare two Excel columns A&B and add in one cell the data of a third column C of the entries not present in A

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three columns, two of them are a list of countries. The third column is a list of numbers corresponding to the countries in column A. 
The formula should compare column A and C and add in a single cell the numbers of the countries not present in list C when compared to A.
I want the output to be only one cell, not a list. 
I've tried with Index & Match and with a Sumproduct and Sumif but I haven't been able to make it work, maybe my syntax was bad.
Thanks!

```
A               B       C         Output  
Austria         1000    Belgium   6000  
Belgium         2000    Spain   
Spain           3000    Portugal  
Portugal        4000  
United Kingdom  5000
```

Comment: something like `{=SUM(B1:B10)-SUM(SUMIF(A1:A10,TRANSPOSE(C1:C10),B1:B10))}` will do the job...

Comment: @DirkReichel Never seen `SUM` and `TRANSPOSE` used like that, would you mind posting an answer detailing the logic of what it is doing so I can add it to my repertoire?

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor created by logic. The evaluate formula tool will show very nicely how the `SUMIF` outputs multiple values... normally there should be no need for the transpose... but some formula at some excel-versions get problems if all inputs use the same kind (row/column)... so I added it (just walking around with my phone right now and can't test it) :P

Comment: Okay yeah i caved and knocked it up in Excel. Makes sense now. Why won't `"<>"&TRANSPOSE(C1:C10)` work though, Excel can be weird at times! Thanks for the response.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help. this is similar to what I had already done. But I was wondering if I could make it without having a substraction. Isn't there a formula that checks for which items in column A are not present in column C, and then adding the corresponding values in B? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment:

```
{=SUM(B1:B10)-SUM(SUMIF(A1:A10,TRANSPOSE(C1:C10),B1:B10))}
```

will do the job...

being able to run tests, it works even without `TRANSPOSE`:

```
{=SUM(B1:B10)-SUM(SUMIF(A1:A10,C1:C10,B1:B10))}
```

or without sumif: (will be slow / uses lots of resources)

```
{=SUM(B1:B10)-SUM((A1:A10=TRANSPOSE(C1:C10))*B1:B10)}
```

Looking for a way without the `'-'`:
It is hard to exclude something, because you would need an `AND` or something like that which is only working column or row-wise (and that doesn't exist)... so it is easier to collect every match and then simply subtract it from the unfiltered list... but if you really want to do it that way:

```
{=SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1:A10,C1:C10,0)),B1:B10))}
=SUMPRODUCT(ISERROR(MATCH(A1:A10,C1:C10,0))*1,B1:B10)
```

Still, it doesn't look very pretty to me while the last one avoids the CSE...